# Why WSO2 IS SAML2SSOAuthenticationService is returning false? (SAML2 SSO)

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

**Scenario**: I've deployed a Jaggery App at WSO2 AS 5.2.1 and I have WSO2 IS 5.0.0 (service pack activated) running two Service Providers with SSO config, one pointing to AS and the other to my Jaggery App.

My acs.jag is a copy o Dashboard application running at IS and configuration is similar too:

```
"saml_config" : {
    "SAML.IdPUrl" : "samlsso",
    "SAML.IssuerID" : "my.jag.app",
    "SAML.LogoutUrl" : "logout",
    "SAML.EnableResponseSigning" : "true",
    "SAML.EnableAssertionSigning" : "true",
    "SAML.EnableRequestSigning" : "true",
    "SAML.SSOAgentCredentialImplClass" : "org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.agent.saml.SSOAgentKeyStoreCredential",
    "SAML.KeyStorePassword" : "wso2carbon",
    "SAML.IdPCertAlias" : "wso2carbon",
    "SAML.PrivateKeyAlias": "wso2carbon",
    "SAML.PrivateKeyPassword" : "wso2carbon",
    "SAML.KeyStore" : "{carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
}
```

**Problem**: After IDP response, the payload is submited to SAML2SSOAuthenticationService and it always return false.

```
<ns:loginResponse xmlns:ns="http://sso.saml2.authenticator.identity.carbon.wso2.org">
  <ns:return>false</ns:return>
</ns:loginResponse>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

[EDIT]
Thanks to @Asela I've noticed this at IS log:
**Problem**:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.saml2.sso.SAML2SSOAuthenticator} 
Authentication Request is rejected. SAMLResponse AudienceRestriction validation failed.
```

In SAML2SSOAuthenticator class, the error is set by Assertion object equals null, but Assertion object isn't null before jaggery call SAML2SSOAuthenticationService.

Comment: If WSO2IS returns the SAML2 Response correctly,  It is some issue with the validation in the WSO2AS,  it is better, if you can trace the SAML response and see...   http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/09/17/troubleshooting-saml2-web-sso-scenarios/

Comment: @Asela thanks for your quick reply. I've edited the question, can you see it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what's missing.
Changed the Claim in the Jaggery App Service Provider to /role && /emailaddress, and now it's working just fine.